# change checkbox status (true/ false) on div click

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

i have div that have image, label and input check-box. what i like when i click on div, it change check-box status from true to false and vise verse

jQuery

```
$(".markerDiv").click(function () {

    if ($(this).find('input:checkbox[name=markerType]').is(":checked")) {

          $(this).find('input:checkbox[name=markerType]').attr("checked", false);
    }
    else {
          $(this).find('input:checkbox[name=markerType]').attr("checked", true);
    }


 alert($(this).find('input:checkbox[name=markerType]').is(":checked"));
});
```

html

```
<div class="markerDiv"  id="maker_school"><label class="marker_label">School</label> <input class="marker_ckeckbox" name="markerType" value="school" type="checkbox"  /> </div> <br />
```

Comment: yh but when you keep clicking on school, it stop functioning ...

Comment: which version of IE are you targeting? You can do this in pure css with the :checked pseudo class

Comment: comment on accepted answer why you choosed it rather than others'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use prop as you been guide through out this blog. As your check-box is in div and because div is registered with click event, it may stop you using check-box. Use e.stopPropagation to make check-box itself click-able too.

```
$('.markerDiv').click(function () {

  if ($(this).find('input:checkbox[name=markerType]').is(":checked")) {

    $(this).find('input:checkbox[name=markerType]').attr("checked", false);
  }
  else {
      $(this).find('input:checkbox[name=markerType]').prop("checked", true);
  }

   alert($(this).find('input:checkbox[name=markerType]').is(":checked"));
});


 $('input[type=checkbox]').click(function (e) {
     e.stopPropagation();
 });
```

Comment: same as another one up there, don't mix attr and prop

Answer (score 6):

You can select checkbox with `children('input[type="checkbox"]')` selector and change its state with the following code

```
$('.markerDiv').on('click', function(){
   var checkbox = $(this).children('input[type="checkbox"]');
   checkbox.prop('checked', !checkbox.prop('checked'));
});
```

Comment: why suggesting `children` rather than `find`?

Comment: @TecHunter Because the `checkbox` element is immediate children of `.markerDiv`. If it was deeper in the tree I would use `find`. I am not sure about the performance side of this, but I'll do some research on it.

Comment: that's a good point if you have value arguments :) +1 for that

Comment: After browsing for a while I found [this site](http://jsperf.com/jquery-children-vs-find/18) to test performance between `find` and `children`, and it seems `find` is indeed faster with such high element count. However, in this case the element count is low and I would guess we can refer to [this site](http://blog.ekini.net/2009/03/16/jquery-children-vs-find-which-is-faster/) saying that `children` is faster. Anyway, it's intresting topic to research, but I would guess in this case it doesn't matter enough to go deeper. :P

Comment: nice catch! interesting subject indeed

Answer (score 6):

You can do it without writing any javaScript/jQuery method.

Just wrap div inside a label:-

```css
div {
  background: red;
  padding: 10px 40px;
}
```

```html
<label for="myCheck">
  <div>
    <input id="myCheck" type="checkbox" />Remember Me!
  </div>
</label>
```

Comment: Please do not link to external resources when you can just embed it directly in your answer.

Comment: Element div is not allowed as a child of element label. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18609554/is-div-inside-label-block-correct

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution would be to put the checkbox inside of the label. That way, no JS/jQuery is required.

If you can't/don't want to do that, you can do the following:-

```
$(".markerDiv").click(function (e) {    
    if (!$(e.target).is('input:checkbox')) {
        var $checkbox = $(this).find('input:checkbox');
        $checkbox.prop('checked', !$checkbox.prop('checked'));
    }
});
```

This is pretty much the same as what you already had. Except it uses `prop()`. The reason yours didn't work properly is because when you use `.attr()` to get the checked property, it refers to the `defaultChecked` state, and not the current state.

From the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/prop/):

> *Nevertheless, the most important concept to remember about the checked
>   attribute is that it does not correspond to the checked property. The
>   attribute actually corresponds to the defaultChecked property and
>   should be used only to set the initial value of the checkbox.*

The only other thing in there is the `if` statement which checks if you clicked on the checkbox itself. The default behaviour interferes with the click handler, so the simplest solution is to only check the checkbox programatically when the checkbox isn't clicked, otherwise leave it to its default behaviour.

Hope that makes sense,

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dBvJE/4/)

Comment: This solution is the simplest and it really works. Clicking on checkbox directly works too. Thanx

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `.prop('checked',true)` instead of `.attr()`. check it out here : http://jsfiddle.net/techunter/VQ5E2/

Or with `.attr` use `attr.('checked','checked')` or `.removeAttr('checked')`. here :
http://jsfiddle.net/techunter/SaRmW/

Optimized code here :

```
$(".markerDiv").click(function () {
    var $checks = $(this).find('input:checkbox[name=markerType]');

    $checks.prop("checked", !$checks.is(":checked"));

    alert($checks.is(":checked"));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/techunter/YymBH/

Comment: although I recommend using `.prop`

Comment: also note the usage of a local variable instead of repeating the selectors

Comment: These solutions not allows clicking on checkbox directly

Answer (score 0):

There is a property 'for' in HTML element 'label'.

```
<div class="markerDiv"  id="maker_school">
    <label class="marker_label" for="markerType">School</label> 
    <input class="marker_ckeckbox" id="markerType" name="markerType" value="school" type="checkbox"  /> 
</div>
```

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/bH3jJ/

You have to set 'id' attribute in your 'input[type="checkbox"]' element and then pass this id into property 'for' in 'label' element.

**Edit:**

If do you like to make in with jQuery, here is solution:

```
$(".markerDiv").click(function () { 
    var checkBox = $('input[name=markerType]', this);

    $(checkBox).prop('checked', !checkBox.is(':checked'));
});
```

with your HTML markup:

```
<div class="markerDiv" id="maker_school">
    <label class="marker_label">School</label>
    <input class="marker_ckeckbox" name="markerType" value="school" type="checkbox"  />
</div>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/QgEL8/1/

Comment: no the label and every thing is working fine, even in alert i am getting current value of check-box onclick, is just not changing to true or false on markerDiv click

Comment: The label is working? As in when you click on the label it toggles the checkbox? I don't think it would be working. Isn't clicking on the label what you are trying to get working? There's nothing else in the div.

Comment: BTW you can nest the `<input>` tag inside the `<label>` tag. Whether you do that or use the `for` attribute, then clicking the label will toggle the checkbox automatically. You don't need *any* JavaScript code for this.

Comment: Are there any arguments why do you think, that the answer is not useful?

Comment: -1 when you only had the `<label for>` part. after that you edited with almost same answer as everyone who posted but you changed the selector from `input:checkbox[name=markerType]` to `input[type="checkbox"]` and I don't see any reason to do this and it's not explained why.

Comment: You are right, i have to use input:checkbox[name=markerType] as in question

Comment: for positing of each element in div purpose i am not nesting <input> inside the label, plus id="maker_school" representing/ displaying image of size 40px by 40px. I am not interesting only label click fires event but the whole div "markerDiv".

Comment: I did not tell you to put <input> inside label. There are two solutions in my answer, which you could use. Even if you don't want to use pure HTML label & input, you could see how to write your JS code. Anyway, i think it's better than in your example in question, but you could think and do what you want, i just tried to give you answer. I hope you already found solution and my answer wasn't so bad.

Comment: @FSou1 after edits your answer is okay but I dunno if you could just keep editing picking part of answers from other people.

Comment: i say thanks for everyone helping me out and i have learned valuable aspects from these discussion so i have voted +1 to all answers on this blog.

Answer (score 0):

I have followed TecHunter and khurram suggestion.

1) don't mix attribute and properties by using only properties attribute but using only this will block input check-box click-able behavior so

2) so use separate function; register input[type=checkbox] with click event, then use  e.stopPropagation() which will ensure running of check-box clickable itself too

```
$('.markerDiv').click(function () {

    var $checks = $(this).find('input:checkbox[name=markerType]');

     $checks.prop("checked", !$checks.is(":checked"));

       //process my data here

 });

$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function (e) {

    e.stopPropagation();

      //process my data here
});
```