# Is <div> inside <label> block correct?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap, it's demo of horizontal form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail1" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Email</label>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail1">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

but I don't want create ID for each `<input>`, so

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="block">
      <span class="col-lg-2 control-label">Email</span>
      <div class="col-lg-10">
        <input type="email" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </label>
  </div>
</form>
```

but `display:block` can't be inside `display:inline`, so I use CSS

```
.block {
  display: block;
}
```

it's working, but is it correct? because I heard that we should not put `display:block` element into `display:inline` element (`label`)

Comment: If you used the [validator](http://validator.w3.org/) you would get the error **Element div not allowed as child of element label in this context**.

Comment: Has any way to do this without setting `id` ?

Comment: Its Wrong to use div inside label element

Comment: Since `label` markup exists primarily for accessibility, it should be used in a manner that is most widely supported by browsers. This means using the `for` and `id` attributes to specify the connection between a label and a control.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

No, HTML does not allow a `<label>` to contain a `<div>`.

---

See [the specification for the label element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-label-element):

> Content model:
>   Phrasing content, but with no descendant labelable elements unless it is the element's labeled control, and no descendant label elements.

Where phrasing content links to:

> Phrasing content is the text of the document, as well as elements that mark up that text at the intra-paragraph level. Runs of phrasing content form paragraphs.
>
> `a abbr area` (if it is a descendant of a map element) `audio b bdi bdo br button canvas cite code data datalist del dfn em embed i iframe img input ins kbd keygen label map mark math meter noscript object output progress q ruby s samp script select small span strong sub sup svg textarea time u var video wbr text`

Comment: Then what is alternative to it? I really need specific divs to check radio button when they are clicked.

Comment: JavaScript. Probably along the lines of `document.getElementById(this.querySelector("label").getAttribute("for")).checked`.

Comment: By the way, is this legit? <label><img></label> ?

Comment: @Kunok if you read the tag list above (in the quoted text) you can see `img` listed. So **yes** images are allowed into labels.

Comment: @Kamafeather IE disagrees

Comment: @Kunok — I've never encountered a problem with IE not supporting images in labels.

Comment: @Quentin   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20198137/image-label-for-input-in-a-form-not-clickable-in-ie11

Comment: Does anyone know whether it's valid to have a `span` as child content with CSS `display: block` or conversely a `div` with `display: inline`?

Comment: @vanthome — If you have a new question, you can click the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) link at the top of every page … and then it can be [closed as a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18930438/putting-a-block-level-span-element-inside-a-p-element).