# Putting a block level <span> element inside a <p> element

Tags: block, inline, html, paragraph

I know that `<p>` is to be used specifically with inline elements. But what if you change an inline element like `<span>` into a block-level element using `{ display:block }` and contain it within a `<p>`?

ie.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>

  p {
    background: red;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    }

  p span {
    display: block;
    background: blue;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    }

</style>
</head>

<body>

<p>
  <span>I am a pizza</span>
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Is that just wrong in every sense of the word? I know it is not common (ie. most would question why I didn't just use a div) but it's a hypothetical situation. It passes validation tests, but is it sloppy as all heck/bad practice? Would you scoff if you read that code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Nesting block level elements inside the <p> tag... right or wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291467/nesting-block-level-elements-inside-the-p-tag-right-or-wrong)

Answer (score -4, accepted):

It's HTML5 valid and it's not that bad in certain situations e.g.

```
<p>
   This is some text <span class="highlight">I am a pizza</span> and this is some more text...
</p>

.highlight {
  background: yellow;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But my specific questions was...if I turned the span intentionally into a block-level element using display: block, would you consider that in total violation of the rules?

Comment: Well, I do not because what if you want something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/KVdPj/). Why not, it's HTML5 valid.

Comment: The answer does not address the question asked.

Answer (score 12):

A `span` element is always a text/inline/phrase element in HTML, and the HTML syntax rules that restrict `p` element content to such elements relate to HTML only. So they are not affected by CSS settings that may make a `span` a block element *in the CSS (rendering) sense*.

In CSS, you can assign any defined value to the `display` property, no matter what the element is like. CSS is ignorant of the meanings of elements as defined in HTML or other markup language specifications.

Thus, there is no formal objection.

Whether it is good style, or otherwise acceptable, is more complicated. There does not seem to be any statement on this in specifications, but it is reasonable to say that you should not change basic rendering features elements in vain. For example, in normal conditions, you should not use `span` and then say `display: block` in CSS, when there is the more logical approach of using `div`. One reason to this principle is that it keeps your document in a better shape in non-CSS rendering situations or when all or some of your style sheet is not applied.

On the other hand, you would not change `display` *in vain* if you have a text paragraph and you wish to render part of its content as a block, e.g. as a centered or indented line, possibly with a background color that stretches through the available width. You cannot use `div` inside `p`, so the more natural markup is not available.

Since the example is not a real one, it is impossible to say whether it is OK to deploy this approach in your case.