# Image label for input in a form not clickable in IE11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11

## The problem

In IE11 the image in the following code is clickable to activate/toggle the input in the label:

```
<label>
    <input type="checkbox"> some text
    <img src="http://placeimg.com/100/100/any" alt="some img">
</label>
```

While the image in the this exactly same code but inside of a `<form>` is not clickable to activate/toggle the input:

```
<form>
<label>
    <input type="checkbox"> some text
    <img src="http://placeimg.com/100/100/any" alt="some img">
</label>
</form>
```

([Demo at jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GYNUS/))

[image: Example]

*Note that in the example animation above I'm clicking the second image, which doesn't work, but clicking on the text works (just did that to demonstrate).*

**This was tested and reproduced on:**

- IE 11.0.9600.16428 on Windows 7 Pro SP1 x64.
- IE 11.0.9600.16438 on Windows RT 8.1 tablet.
- IE 11.0.9600.17105 on Windows 7 Pro SP1 x64.
- IE 11.0.10240.16431 on *Windows 10*

This issue does not occur in IE9, IE10, Microsoft *Edge*, and other browsers.

## Questions:

1. Can this be solved **without** JS while still using image tags?
2. If not, what other possible solutions are there?
3. *(Optional)* Why doesn't the image in the second example trigger the input element (while doing it in the first)?

Answer (score 114, accepted):

One way to fix this is with `pointer-events: none` on the image, and adjusting the label with for example `display: inline-block`. (`pointer-events` [is supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events) in IE11.)

```
label{
    display: inline-block;
}
label img{
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

([Demo at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VdJ9m/))

Comment: If one uses the bootstrap framework, then all images with the class `img-responsive` get the `display:block` style. In that case, you need to add an extra line to the `label img` css. This should be added: `display: inline!important`.

Comment: why does `pointer-events:none` fix this? Why does the `display` property of the image matter? This answer does not at all explain what the actual issue is.

Comment: @chiliNUT: The IE11 bug is that clicking the image element doesn't do what's it's supposed to. By setting `pointer-events: none` on the image and making the label element at least as large as the image the click is registered on the label element instead, in which case IE does what it's supposed to.

Comment: by not do what its supposed to do, what does it do instead? why does cancelling pointer events fix it? What pointer event is taking place that causes it to break?

Comment: @chiliNUT, what it does and what should be done can be seen in the question. I just explained why setting `pointer-events: none` fixes this. What event? The click event. For the specifics on why and how MS implemented this IE bug, are better directed at MS.

Comment: Great answer, but in my case I need pointer/mouse events. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Might be some quirk with my setup, but I also needed `label img{position:relative}` for IE11 on Windows 7.

Comment: one just need to love that jsFiddle does not work on IE11 so you cannot tested the solution :)

Comment: @sKopheK when I wrote the answer it did. You can add `/show` at the end of a jsFiddle URL to at least see the result in IE11 (works): http://jsfiddle.net/VdJ9m/show

Comment: @Qtax sorry buddy, with the link provided in the latest message it works. it's just that the jsFiddle does not communicate with IE anymore :)

Answer (score 8):

Is a bit older question, but as its pretty high in google search, I'll post here one more answer that fixes this in all IE versions.

.

The checkbox/radio has to be **outside** of label, it has to have own unique ID and label has to have attribute **for** which contains the ID of checkbox/radio its related to:

```
<label for="my_lovely_checkbox">Hello good friend</label>
<input type="checkbox" value="Hello" id="my_lovely_checkbox">
```

If you done that and if you use PHP (which you probably are), you can use this piece of code:

```
if (preg_match('~MSIE|Internet Explorer~i', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) || (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Trident/7.0; rv:11.0') !== false)) {
    ?>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("label img").on("click", function() {
                $("#" + $(this).parents("label").attr("for")).click();
            });
        });
    </script>
    <?
}
```

I know its JS, but there is actually no other fix for `=< IE10` without JS usage.

It detects all IE, versions (IE10 and 11 included, have no idea about Spartan tho, i think it does not detect that one).

Ps.: Answer above me does not actually work for IE8, IE9 and IE10. Just so you know.

Comment: This bug was not present in IE10 when I tested, as I wrote in the question. Are you stating that IE10 also has this bug? Demo?

Comment: @Qtax Its still there. i tried it right now in chrome and IE10. Works in Chrome, does not in IE10: http://jsfiddle.net/v4rz346s/ But you have to have IE set to Edge and not IE 10 (in F12 -> Emulation menu). Problem is, that Edge is set as default, so unless user changes that to IE10, it won't work.

Comment: Tested your (and my original) example in IE10 (real IE10 in a VM), can click on images just fine. No bug there. So you are probably doing something wrong with your testing.

Comment: What do you mean by real IE10? I have real IE10 installed on my Win 7 PC. If you push F12 and go to Emulation tab. Whats your document mode? For me its Edge (Default). Works only when I select 10. And as Edge is default, it should not work for everybody. And even if it works in IE10, the answer you got provided works ONLY in IE 11 as you can see here: http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events

Comment: By real IE10 I mean not emulated in some other IE version. I have a [clean windows 7 VM with IE10](https://www.modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools#downloads). The only thing I do is open the link [you](http://jsfiddle.net/v4rz346s/show) ([and I](http://jsfiddle.net/GYNUS/show)) posted, and I can click on the images to select the options (and checkboxes). Which means no bug. At least not in the normal case, when not messing with F12 and emulation options.

Comment: Some comments on your code: `$.live()` has been deprecated for some time, and it wouldn't work the code in question anyway (e.g. the labels have no `for` attribute).

Comment: @Qtax Ah so you think I dont have IE 10 :D Nope, I have IE 10, the official one from Microsoft (I do not consider VM a real PC, you might not get unchanged offiicial windows with the IE how its IRL). But still, as I told, the answer above works only in IE 11, in which this works well, so IDK why its actually accepted one if it does not help in IE 8 to IE 10 (included)............... Yeah I know, Ill change the code to onclick. Its an older code I used and since it works well, I never bothered to update it. And he had a problem, because he placed checkbox inside label, which is wrong :)

Comment: *"The checkbox/radio has to be outside of label, it has to have own unique ID and label has to have attribute for which contains the ID of checkbox/radio its related to"*, do you mean in general? In that case that is wrong. Or are you talking about your example? In that case how is that relevant? This question is about a bug in IE11. This bug does not occur in any other IE version, so to answer it for any other IE version is irrelevant.

Comment: @Qtax Yes, you can have either FOR or put the element (checkbox) inside label, but for this version of fix its supposed to be as I said. Also, I tried it in multiple IE versions and it is not related to IE 11 only.