# Use image instead of radio button not working with form tag in IE

Tags: css

I am showing the thumbnail images in the user select option instead of radio button. Here is the demo http://jsfiddle.net/a3Lj4b1g/.

```
            <div class="container">
             <form>
               <div class="form-group">
                  <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="fb" value="1" />
                      <img src="http://placehold.it/80/35d/fff&text=1"/>
                  </label>

                  <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="fb" value="2"/>
                      <img src="http://placehold.it/80/35d/fff&text=2"/>
                  </label>

                  <label>
                    <input id="fb3" type="radio" name="fb" value="3" />
                      <img src="http://placehold.it/80/35d/fff&text=3" />
                  </label>
                 </div>
              </form>
            </div>
```

This works fine in Chrome and Mozilla but not in IE. If I remove the form tag it works fine in IE also.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Which version of IE?

Comment: IE11 Edge.When I change the Document mode (any value other than Edge) it works as expected, any suggestions although I can restrict it to a different Document mode using meta tag

Comment: It looks like that solves my issue but let me do some more testing.

Comment: Did you manage to fix this?

Comment: Yes from this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20198137/image-label-for-input-in-a-form-not-clickable-in-ie11