# Image label for input file not clickable

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, label

In IE7, IE8, IE9 the image label in the following code is not opening browse window on click:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Image label</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS Toolkit styles -->

</head>

<style type="text/css">
label{
    display: inline-block;
}
label img{
    pointer-events: none;
}
</style>

<body>
  <form>
    <label for="test">
      <img src="http://anniekateshomeschoolreviews.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Online-picture1-300x203.jpg">
    </label>
    <input type="file" id="test">
  </form>
</body> 
</html>
```

Is there any way of fixing this problem.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Image label for input in a form not clickable in IE11](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20198137/image-label-for-input-in-a-form-not-clickable-in-ie11)

Answer (score 0):

http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/using_images_as
check this out hope thiss will work

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this without setting id and label for. Position relative should be used to wrap this section as well.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Image label</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS Toolkit styles -->

</head>

<style type="text/css">
label{
    display: inline-block;
}
label img{
    pointer-events: none;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
  input[type="file"]{
      position: absolute;
      top: 5px;
      left: 5px;
      width: 108px;
      height: 130px;
      font-size: 100px;
      text-align: right;
      filter: alpha(opacity=0);
      opacity: 0;
      outline: none;
      background: white;
      cursor: inherit;
      display: block;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <form>
    <label>
      <img src="http://anniekateshomeschoolreviews.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Online-picture1-300x203.jpg">
    </label>
    <input type="file" id="test">
  </form>
</body> 
</html>
```