# Click on image in label tag does not trigger on Windows Phone

Tags: html, windows-phone

I have to use an image instead of text as a label for a radio element. It works fine on all devices except for Windows Phone. The simplified code can be found in [this example](http://plnkr.co/SyaSCxtZ8LUx04vDnlhe):

```
<form action="#" method="post">
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="foo" value="0" />
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50"><br />
        text0
    </label>
</form>
```

It makes no difference if the input field is inside the label or referenced with for. I tried to use jQuery and trigger('input') too. But no chance to bring Windows Phone to check the radio element except for click on the element itself or a text label. How can I use an image as a label which works on Windows Phone too?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Image label for input in a form not clickable in IE11](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20198137/image-label-for-input-in-a-form-not-clickable-in-ie11)

Comment: I tried the css-solution, but it's not working on Windows Phone...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a "click"-Element positioned above all other elements inside the label (pseudocode):

```
<form action="#" method="post">
    <label style="position:relative;">
        <input type="radio" name="foo" value="0" />
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50"><br />
        text0
        <span style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;z-index:2;"></span>
    </label>
</form>
```