# Checkbox image styling not working correctly within form on IE

Tags: css, forms, internet-explorer, checkbox

I've got a form in which I've got checkboxes styled with images. All working nicely in Chrome, FF, Edge... but not IE.

Basically, the CSS styling works how I want it to in IE, when the checkboxes are NOT within a form, but as soon as the form tags go around them, they stop working properly. Instead, rather than clicking the image to get the checked effect, I have to click beside the image.

Anyone help me out with what I have to do to make it work correctly in IE?
I've tried it in IE 11. Why would making it within a form cause it to change behaviour?

I'm not a natural coder, and most of the CSS below was adapted from another question I found on here.

Jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/vpLf8vpw/5/

HTML

```
<form> 
   <input id="cb1" name="product1[]" type="checkbox" value=" Classic switch" />
   <label for="cb1">
       <img src="http://www.4jewelersonly.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/16/2015/03/127880648-670x670.jpg" alt="" />
   </label>

   <input id="cb2" name="product2[]" type="checkbox" value=" Right angle switch" />
    <label for="cb2">
        <img src="http://www.4jewelersonly.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/16/2015/03/127880648-670x670.jpg" alt="" />
    </label>

    <input id="cb3" name="product3[]" type="checkbox" value=" Adaptor" />
    <label for="cb3">
        <img src="http://www.4jewelersonly.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/16/2015/03/127880648-670x670.jpg" alt="" />
    </label>

    <input id="cb4" name="product4[]" type="checkbox" value=" Blow switch" />
    <label for="cb4">
        <img src="http://www.4jewelersonly.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/16/2015/03/127880648-670x670.jpg" alt="" />
    </label>

    <input id="cb5" name="product5[]" type="checkbox" value=" Cable" />
    <label for="cb5">
        <img src="http://www.4jewelersonly.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/16/2015/03/127880648-670x670.jpg" alt="" />
    </label>
```

CSS

```
input[type="checkbox"][id^="cb"] {
    display: none;
}

label {


border: none;
  padding: none;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

label img {
  height: 125px;
  width: 125px;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}


:checked + label img {
  transform: scale(1);
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px #ff0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a duplicate of another question: [Image label for input in a form not clickable in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20198137/image-label-for-input-in-a-form-not-clickable-in-ie11)

updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dnptmydo/

```css
input[type="checkbox"][id^="cb"] {
  display: none;
}

label {
  border: none;
  padding: none;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin: none;
  /* cursor: pointer; */
}

label img {
  height: 125px;
  width: 125px;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  pointer-events: none;
}


:checked + label img {
  transform: scale(1);
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px #ff0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<form>
 

    
 
     <input id="cb1" name="product1[]" type="checkbox" value=" Classic switch" />
     <label for="cb1">
      <img src="http://www.4jewelersonly.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/16/2015/03/127880648-670x670.jpg" alt="" />
     </label>
   
     <input id="cb2" name="product2[]" type="checkbox" value=" Right angle switch" />
     <label for="cb2">
      <img src="http://www.4jewelersonly.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/16/2015/03/127880648-670x670.jpg" alt="" />
     </label>
   
     <input id="cb3" name="product3[]" type="checkbox" value=" Adaptor" />
     <label for="cb3">
      <img src="http://www.4jewelersonly.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/16/2015/03/127880648-670x670.jpg" alt="" />
     </label>
   
     <input id="cb4" name="product4[]" type="checkbox" value=" Blow switch" />
     <label for="cb4">
      <img src="http://www.4jewelersonly.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/16/2015/03/127880648-670x670.jpg" alt="" />
     </label>
    
     <input id="cb5" name="product5[]" type="checkbox" value=" Cable" />
     <label for="cb5">
      <img src="http://www.4jewelersonly.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/16/2015/03/127880648-670x670.jpg" alt="" />
     </label>
          </form>
```

Comment: Thanks. I did search, but didn't find that one. Problem solved!