# Use div as radio-button

Tags: html, css

How can I use a `div` as radio button ?

I mean that :

- you can select a `div` and then it is bordered blue
- you can only select one of them

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, you can use 'div' as radio button and will work as radio button groups. But for this you'll need Javascript. I've created a script for that using JQuery. Here is the source--

```js
$('.radio-group .radio').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().find('.radio').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    var val = $(this).attr('data-value');
    //alert(val);
    $(this).parent().find('input').val(val);
});
```

```css
.radio-group{
    position: relative;
}

.radio{
    display:inline-block;
    width:15px;
    height: 15px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background-color:lightblue;
    border: 2px solid lightblue;
    cursor:pointer;
    margin: 2px 0; 
}

.radio.selected{
    border-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h2>Select an option (You will get it's value displayed in the text input field!)</h2>
<form method="post" action="send.php">
  <div class="radio-group">
      <div class='radio' data-value="One"></div>1
      <div class='radio' data-value="Two"></div>2
      <div class='radio' data-value="Three"></div>3
      <br/>
      <input type="text" id="radio-value" name="radio-value" />
  </div>
  
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer. That was exactly what I wanted

Comment: but how can I submit the selected number to a php file after clicking on a button?

Comment: I've just made an edit for that. There is a text box now, where you get the value. You make it type="hidden". So, now you can send the value to PHP by using Form submit like you do!

Comment: Wow thank you very much. That works perfect for me! :D

Comment: Nice, but you wil miss some accessability that normaly comes with radio buttons, for example selecting next/previous with arrow keys

Comment: @Michiel, my answer was based on the question. Tom wanted to use DIV. But below there is a CSS solution, if you prefer.

Answer (score 43):

If you want a **CSS Only** solution, this is an excellent one :

```css
.labl {
    display : block;
    width: 400px;
}
.labl > input{ /* HIDE RADIO */
    visibility: hidden; /* Makes input not-clickable */
    position: absolute; /* Remove input from document flow */
}
.labl > input + div{ /* DIV STYLES */
    cursor:pointer;
    border:2px solid transparent;
}
.labl > input:checked + div{ /* (RADIO CHECKED) DIV STYLES */
    background-color: #ffd6bb;
    border: 1px solid #ff6600;
}
```

```html
<label class="labl">
    <input type="radio" name="radioname" value="one_value" checked="checked"/>
    <div>Small</div>
</label>
<label class="labl">
    <input type="radio" name="radioname" value="another" />
    <div>Small</div>
</label>
```

Inspired by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17541614/use-image-instead-of-radio-button)

Comment: Thanks a lot. this solved my problem on effective way.

Comment: `div` inside `label` is not alowed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18609554/is-div-inside-label-block-correct

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple solution.

HTML

```
<div class="option first">1</div>
<div class="option second">2</div>
<div class="option third">3</div>
<div class="option fourth">4</div>
```

CSS

```
.option
{
    background-color:red;
    margin: 10px auto;
}

.option.active
{
    border:1px solid blue;
}
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(
function()
    {
        $(".option").click(
            function(event)
        {
            $(this).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
        }
        );
    });
```

[link](https://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/u8pjqwgd/)

Comment: Thank you too. I think this is The simplest solution 

Answer (score 0):

Check this out. Strict HTML/CSS only solution (no divs inside labels):

```css
input {display: none;}
label {display: block;}

input + div  {
  background: orange;
}

input + div label {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input:checked + div {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" id="one" name="test" value="ONE">
<div><label for="one">ONE</label></div>

<input type="radio" id="two" name="test" value="TWO">
<div><label for="two">TWO</label></div>

<input type="radio" id="three" name="test" value="THREE">
<div><label for="three">THREE</label></div>
```

This way uses a label inside a div (as opposed to a div inside a label, which is illegal). You can put any other elements in the div.

If you want the entire div to be clickable as a radio button, its label must cover its full width and height. The easiest solution for all cases is `label {position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%;}` along with `input + div {position: relative;}`. And place the label last among any other elements inside the div.