# Using custom radio button with selection state for narrator

Tags: javascript, html, css, radio-button, radiobuttonlist

I am following the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32935435/use-div-as-radio-button) by @Xahed Kamal (The one with 7 upvotes as of now) to create custom radio buttons. But the narrator in this case is not reading out the selection state of the radio button. What is the best way make the narrator read the selection state here? Does using aria-label, aria-labelledby or aria-describedby creates any issue from accessibility perspective?

PS: When we use input type as radio button, narrator reads out 'selected' or 'not selected' while navigating through the radio button. But as mentioned in the link above, when we create custom radio button with html and css , the narrator does not read 'selected' or 'not selected' while navigating through them. How can that narrator behavior be simulated in the custom radio buttons to read 'selected' or 'not selected' as appropriate?

Comment: You'll get better answers if you restate the question in full and give enough background that we understand the context of the problem.

Comment: Added some more text. Please let me know if it still seems to be ambiguous.