# Can't select div inside a label with input:checked

Tags: php, html

I have this markup and I want to select `#menu-main-menu-1` when input is `:checked`. But it just does not work. Where did it go wrong?

```
<input type="checkbox" name="name" value="" id="mobile-trigger">
    <label for="mobile-trigger">
      <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <div class="button-overlay"></div>
      <div class="menu-overlay"></div>
        <?php wp_nav_menu( $defaults ); ?>
    </label>

      input:checked + label #menu-main-menu-1 {
    top: 92px;
    pointer-events: auto;
  }
```

Update, my markup from source code:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="name" value="" id="mobile-trigger">
    <label for="mobile-trigger">
      <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <div class="button-overlay"></div>
      <div class="menu-overlay"></div>
        <ul id="menu-main-menu-1" class="navigation-small"><li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-427"><a href="http://localhost:8888/category/portfolio/">Portfolio</a></li>
```

[Blog](http://localhost:8888/category/blog/)
About
Contact

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is <div> inside <label> block correct?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18609554/is-div-inside-label-block-correct)

Comment: Yes, that does answer my question. Thank you!