# How to set :disabled pseudo element/class on :before pseudo element

Tags: html, css

I want to change color of my toggle button when it get disabled. I Implemented this toggle using :before fetaure of css . 
Code is present at https://jsfiddle.net/sachin8085/adm5t7rz/6/

```
<div>
Step 1> click on toggle button <br />

step 2> click on disable button <br />

result > Blue color of switch should change to gray when it get disabled.

</div>
<div>



<label class="toggleswitch" style="hidden: true" id="lblToggle">
  <input id="enableSN" name="enableSN" class="switch-input" type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="appEnabled" (ngModelChange)="switchChange($event)">

  <div class="slider"></div>
</label>

<div>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btnDisabled" text="disable" onclick="ondisabledclick()"> disable</button>
</div>
<div id="demo">
  Sample
</div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
/* The switch - the box around the slider */

.toggleswitch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}


/* Hide default HTML checkbox */

.toggleswitch input {
  display: none;
}
```

Not able to find a way to set a background color property of :before element when its parent get disabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know if it is what you looking for

```
.disabled .slider:before{
  background-color: red;
}
.disabled input:checked + .slider:before{
  background-color: green;
}
```

example: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gpc0tghj/)

And also if I'm correct you shouldn't use block elements (`div`) inside label, its wrong behaviour

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18609649/1121576

Comment: yeah but you wanted to change color when the slider is disabled, so I don't get it? what you want to achive...Quote "I want to change color of my toggle button when it get disabled. " I did what you wanted.

Comment: oh okay sorry, but still code with checked is working like you can see on jsfiddle just check slider and click disabled then you'll get green color.

Comment: Hmm it works as it supposed to work, .disabled class is given on parent element of input and slider so when label hasClass("disabled") then input:checked + (sibling) .slider have desired attributes.

Comment: I'm an idiot... Not sure where my brain is today. Sorry for wasting your time, haha.