# Block Element like <div> with `display: inline` inside <label> block correct?

Tags: html

As specified [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html#the-label-element) and debated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18609554/is-div-inside-label-block-correct/18609649?noredirect=1#comment84782731_18609649) it is invalid to put a `DIV` tag inside a `LABEL`. What if, however, you make the element an inline element with the CSS rule `display: inline`?

My guess is that this won't change anything, because the spec does not mention CSS at all. I don't see however how this should go together with Web Components that allow me to build my very own form control just from DIVs with CSS styling and proper ARIA a11y declarations.

Answer (score 0):

Correct, CSS is independent and have no influence on document validity. So that construct will be still invalid ( according to specification and according to w3c validator ).